# RewriteCond seams not to work well

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a htaccess with this content:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /new/

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)\.(jpg|css|js|gif|png)$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

The URL im working on is some like:

```
http://www.example.xy/new/
```

When I call a link like this:

```
<a href="aaa/bbb/ccc">test</a>
```

URL should come up with

```
http://www.example.xy/new/aaa/bbb/ccc
```

Problem is, no matter what I do, all my css, js, and images are gone because I have them included like

```
<link href="style.css" ... />
```

this ends up in

```
<link href="aaa/bbb/ccc/style.css" ... />
```

how can I deny this or what am I doing wrong?

My .htaccess is based on several tutorials and some qoogle searched posts...

Comment: `RewriteCond seams not to work well` works fine, It's the implementation.

Comment: What is with the implementation ?

Comment: FYI, your rewrite rule only triggers if the script filename is not a file, not a directory, and if the request is not for an image, css, or js.

Comment: @Kenney that is exactly what I expact. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> RewriteCond seams not to work well

works fine, It's the implementation

Add this to your html head section to fix your css, js problem.

```
<base href="http://www.yoursite.com" />
```

Comment: I tried this and it ended up with `http://www.yoursite.com/styles.css` even if I entered **`<base href="http://www.yoursite.com/new/">`** Starkeen's hint brought me the correct input. But +1 for here because actully the answere is right